# Mockito PotentialStubbingProblem when trying to write unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I want to write unit test case for getDashboardRfqs() method in DashboardServiceImpl class. Changing when() statement to doReturn() or adding @MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT) to the test class as it is suggested in the exception log won't solve the problem. I am getting the error below. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code? Thank you.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'map' method:
    modelMapper.map(
    com.commencis.sova.model.service.SVCDashboardRfqsServiceResponse@36074e47,
    class com.commencis.sova.model.SVCDashboardRfqsResponse
);
    -> at com.commencis.sova.service.impl.DashboardServiceImpl.getDashboardRfqs(DashboardServiceImpl.java:66)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. modelMapper.map(null, null);
      -> at com.commencis.sova.service.DashboardServiceTest.getDashboardRfqs_noSortSearchFilter_AllRfq(DashboardServiceTest.java:91)
Typically, stubbing argument mismatch indicates user mistake when writing tests.
Mockito fails early so that you can debug potential problem easily.
However, there are legit scenarios when this exception generates false negative signal:
  - stubbing the same method multiple times using 'given().will()' or 'when().then()' API
    Please use 'will().given()' or 'doReturn().when()' API for stubbing.
  - stubbed method is intentionally invoked with different arguments by code under test
    Please use default or 'silent' JUnit Rule (equivalent of Strictness.LENIENT).
For more information see javadoc for PotentialStubbingProblem class.

    at com.commencis.sova.service.impl.DashboardServiceImpl.getDashboardRfqs(DashboardServiceImpl.java:66)
    at com.commencis.sova.service.DashboardServiceTest.getDashboardRfqs_noSortSearchFilter_AllRfq(DashboardServiceTest.java:93)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

My code:

> DashboardServiceTest.java

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class DashboardServiceTest extends AbstractServiceTestBase {
    @InjectMocks
    private DashboardServiceImpl dashboardService;

    @Mock
    private RfqDashboardCustomRepository rfqDashboardCustomRepository;

    @Mock
    private DashboardFilterViewRepository dashboardFilterViewRepository;

    @Mock
    private BaseUnitService baseUnitService;

    @Test
    public void getDashboardRfqs_noSortSearchFilter_AllRfq() {
        final SVCDashboardRfqsResponse expectedResponse = DashboardMockGenerator.createSVCDashboardRfqsResponse();

        final SVCDashboardRfqRequest request = DashboardMockGenerator.createSVCDashboardRfqRequest();

        final Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, DashboardConstant.PAGE_SIZE);
        final Page<RfqDashboardDto> rfqDashboardDtos = DashboardMockGenerator.createRfqDashboardDtos(pageable);
        final BaseUnit weightUnitName = new BaseUnit();

        weightUnitName.setShortName(DashboardConstant.UNIT_SHORT_NAME);

        final SVCDashboardRfqsServiceResponse serviceResponse = new SVCDashboardRfqsServiceResponse();

        serviceResponse.setRfqDashboardDtos(rfqDashboardDtos);
        serviceResponse.setWeightUnitShortName(weightUnitName.getShortName());

        when(rfqDashboardCustomRepository.getDashboardRfqs(request, pageable)).thenReturn(rfqDashboardDtos);
        when(baseUnitService.getBaseUnitById(request.getWeightUnitID())).thenReturn(weightUnitName);
        when(getModelMapper().map(eq(serviceResponse), eq(SVCDashboardRfqsResponse.class))).thenReturn(expectedResponse);

        final SVCDashboardRfqsResponse actualResponse = dashboardService.getDashboardRfqs(request);

        assertSame(expectedResponse.getRfqs(), actualResponse.getRfqs());
    }
}
```

> DashboardServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DashboardServiceImpl extends AbstractService implements DashboardService {

    private final RfqDashboardCustomRepository rfqDashboardCustomRepository;
    private final BaseUnitService baseUnitService;

    @Override
    public SVCDashboardRfqsResponse getDashboardRfqs(final SVCDashboardRfqRequest svCDashboardRfqRequest) {
        final int pageNumber = svCDashboardRfqRequest.getPageNumber() - 1;
        final Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, svCDashboardRfqRequest.getPageSize());

        final Page<RfqDashboardDto> rfqPages =
            rfqDashboardCustomRepository.getDashboardRfqs(svCDashboardRfqRequest, pageable);

        if (rfqPages.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ServiceException(ErrorTypeEnum.NO_DATA);
        }

        final BaseUnit weightUnitName = baseUnitService.getBaseUnitById(svCDashboardRfqRequest.getWeightUnitID());

        final SVCDashboardRfqsServiceResponse serviceResponse =
            createSVCDashboardRfqsServiceResponse(rfqPages, weightUnitName.getShortName());

        return getModelMapper().map(serviceResponse, SVCDashboardRfqsResponse.class);
    }

    private SVCDashboardRfqsServiceResponse createSVCDashboardRfqsServiceResponse(final Page<RfqDashboardDto> rfqPages,
        final String weightUnitShortName) {

        final SVCDashboardRfqsServiceResponse serviceResponse = new SVCDashboardRfqsServiceResponse();

        serviceResponse.setRfqDashboardDtos(rfqPages);
        serviceResponse.setWeightUnitShortName(weightUnitShortName);

        return serviceResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `SVCDashboardRfqsResponse` and `SVCDashboardRfqRequest` classes and mocks have implemented `equals` and `hashcode` in a proper and suitable way?

Comment: Yes. I believe they are suitable. This is the related equals method for SVCDashboardRfqsResponse 

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    SVCDashboardRfqsResponse dashboardRfqsResponse = (SVCDashboardRfqsResponse) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.rfqs, dashboardRfqsResponse.rfqs) &&
        Objects.equals(this.totalItemNum, dashboardRfqsResponse.totalItemNum) &&
        Objects.equals(this.maxPageNum, dashboardRfqsResponse.maxPageNum);
  }